# How to find out if "debug mode" is enabled

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

How can a Java program find out if it is running in debug mode?

The application should behave a bit different in regular “full speed” mode than in “debug mode” (when a debugger is attached, when running in debug mode). The application communicates over TCP with either another computer, another process, or within itself. My co-worker wants us to use `Socket.setSoTimeout(1000)` by default, so that reads from the socket can block for at most 1 second. When debugging, this is not enough of course, and the application stops working as it should. So a solution would be to set the `SO_TIMEOUT` higher, but just in debug mode (for example: unlimited). Now, I don't always set breakpoints or don't want use a debug build where I could set the “debug” property myself. Sometimes I attach the debugger (remote debugging). I'm mainly using Eclipse so a solution that just works there is OK.

Possible answers include:

1. To find out if run in debug mode, use the following method in `java.lang.management.*` or `javax.management.*` ...
2. Your co-worker is wrong for reason X, you shouldn't set `SO_TIMEOUT` to 1 second by default.

### Update

I know about the system property approach, but I leave the question open to solve my original question.

Comment: @will Your definition of "debug mode" does not match my definition, and you have a very different use case. In your case, I assume using a configuration setting (system property or other) is just fine. For my use case, it's not.

Comment: Since you are obviously not a beginner in programming I just wanted to know why you try to avoid the system property approach, since you surely know that it will be the most future proof and flexible solution?

Comment: @thehandofNOD the system property approach is fine for some use cases, but it's not as convenient. I was looking for a way to automate this. As you can see from the votes on the answers, many others are also interested in having an automated way.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I found it out myself now:

```
boolean isDebug = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().
    getInputArguments().toString().indexOf("jdwp") >= 0;
```

This will check if the [Java Debug Wire Protocol](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdwp-spec.html) agent is used.

Comment: Sure, this works, but that's tight coupling to something that doesn't have anything to do with the program.

Comment: It is a hack because there is no official API to find out if running in debug mode. A system property would be nice. But in the case described above, the program *should* behave differently in debug mode. It's completely on purpose. I just don't want to set the system property *manually* whenever I debug.

Comment: For remote debugging I check {jvmops.indexOf( "runjdwp:" ) > 0 );}

Comment: @RobAu So probably it should be `indexOf("jdwp") >= 0`, to match both `-agentlib:jdwp` and `runjdwp`. I will change my answer.

Comment: sweet, just what I was looking for.

Comment: it didnt work here with message: `>unknown type "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory"<`

Comment: Good answer. `contains("jdwp")` would be more readable than `indexOf("jdwp") >= 0` though.

Comment: Java 8: `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains("jdwp"))`

Comment: Needs contains("debug") for netbeans (at least for 8.2)

Answer (score 13):

Make the timeout configurable. The simplest way is to just use a system property and read it with [`Integer.getInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger-java.lang.String-int-):

```
private final static int SOCKET_TIMEOUT =
  Integer.getInteger("com.yourapp.module.socketTimeout", 1000); // default 1 sec
```

Then, when starting your app for debugging, just set the property from the command line (or an appropriate config file, depending on the environment your app runs in):

```
java -Dcom.yourapp.module.socketTimeout=1000000 MainClass
```

This is good because it does not magically alter the behavior when you fire the app up in a debugger, and you can change the timeout when not debugging (for example, if you need to run it somewhere with a slow connection, some day).

(Of course, if your system already uses a config file, it may be appropriate to add this value as an entry there instead.)

As to whether one second is an appropriate timeout... that depends completely on the app. Sometimes it's better to give a correct answer *eventually*, other times failing quickly is better than waiting for success.

Comment: `Integer.getInteger(..)`? Darn, I didn't know that one. Cool (+1)

Comment: This is a valid solution of course, but it requires a manual step: setting the system property at startup. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Just set a `com.yourapp.debug=true` system property if running in debug mode and have your application check it. If it's the default value, then you're not running in debug mode. This can be done in the Eclipse Debug configurations, which means you don't need to type it in every time you want to debug the program.

Comment: @ThomasMueller However you only need to do it once, no matter how many times you may want to debug your application.

Comment: *Once per machine. If you have multiple devs, with multiple IDEs, it's still very much worth not having a manual step here, imo.

Comment: @LadyCailin: Disagree. Just because you have multiple devs and IDEs it's not a good idea to fill your application code with environment settings since you would clutter your code. Might be that for now it's only 1 setting which needs adapted, but with time there will be more and more. So it's a good idea to keep your code "platform"/"environment" independent. Which is what makes JAVA so cool

Answer (score 6):

You're solving the wrong problem. Your program doesn't need to know this unless it's dealing with eclipse or jvm internals.

### Solution

Use a system property with a default value:

```
int timeout = Integer.parseInt( 
    System.getProperty("socket.timeout", "1000"));
socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
```

And in the debug launch configuration, just add

```
-Dsocket.timeout=20000
```

to the call parameters

(If you don't specify the system property, the default value will be used)

### References

- [System Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) section in the Sun
  Java Tutorial
- [System.getProperty(prop, def)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) javadocs

Comment: Same here: I wanted to avoid having to set a system property manually.