# How to find out if a Java process was started in debugger?

Tags: java, debugging

I sometimes use a timer to call System.exit in order to kill my throw-away code snippet after few seconds, which is quite useful in case it eats 100% CPU and Windows gets irresponsible because of this. It's quite handy, except in case I start it in debugger. In debugger I'd like to disable it automatically, otherwise I forget it and my debugged process gets killed. **Can I find out if a process was started in debugger?**

<sup>Note: I know I should not use this for anything serious. I'm not going to.</sup>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out if "debug mode" is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776204/how-to-find-out-if-debug-mode-is-enabled)

Comment: You're right - however, I could find it. So probably it's better not to close this question. I'd never figure out the wording **debug mode enabled**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776204/how-to-find-out-if-debug-mode-is-enabled). This checks for the [JDWP](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdwp-spec.html).

Basically:

```
boolean isDebug = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().
    getInputArguments().toString().indexOf("-agentlib:jdwp") > 0;
```

Comment: Cool, it works. The only problem: I need to wait for 10 minutes until I can accept this answer.