# Third party library (JAR) does not work in debug mode (Java)

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, jvm-hotspot

In my java project I use a third party library (jar) and call a function of that library at start.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   long handle = Library.method(params);
   if (0 == handle) {
      // error
   }
}
```

Use eclipse for the development. The question is, when I run the project (call the main) in RUN mode, I get the handle. But when I call with DEBUG mode (without any breakpoints attached), I do not get the handle. (The run/debug settings are the same, no additional VM or program parameters)

Question:

- How can the library detect that it is called in the debug mode and
  prevent returning the handle?
- How can I debug this project (I need
  some debug)

Comment: Can you name the library?

Comment: Its a commercial library for license protection and software based dongle, I do not think it is a good idea to name it here. Sorry.

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776204/how-to-find-out-if-debug-mode-is-enabled?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I've referenced this question in my answer.

Comment: sorry, i did not see that. ok, marked as useful and accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can the library detect that it is called in the debug mode and prevent returning the handle?

There are ways, for instance:

> [How to find out if "debug mode" is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776204/how-to-find-out-if-debug-mode-is-enabled)

But it is surely not possible to assemble the complete list of possibilities.

> How can I debug this project (I need some debug)

You'll either need to find a debuggable version (maybe available from the developer of the library for additional fees?) or overcome the protection.

One-guy-I-know-who-isn't-me would for instance first try to disassemble the library to find out how is it actually protected. If disassembly succeeds then it might be even possible to remove the protection.