# Can a Java application detect that a debugger is attached?

Tags: java, debugging

I know about the (jvm) startup options to have the jvm wait until a debugger is attached - this is not what I mean here.

Is it possible from within Java code to also detect attachment of a debugger, so that I could e.g. write a "script" that is doing some stuff and then at a certain point make my app wait for the debugger?

Comment: Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990147/check-if-a-debugger-is-attached-during-the-execution-of-a-unit-test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The options are JVM options, and no Javacode is executed before the debugger connects. You can however let the app start, and spinloop on a getter for a variable, which you set from the debugger to let your app continue.

Comment: I know that those are jvm options (this is what I meant with my first phrase). Interesting idea with the variable; close to what I want.

Comment: So, there's no `Debugger.IsAttached` for Java? -- Super lame.

Comment: Hmmm, after some more searching, seems like for Android there is a `Debug.isDebuggerConnected()` -- too bad there's nothing for regular Java.

Comment: If you just want to know if a debugging is enabled in the current JVM session, then you can use `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().contains("-Xdebug")`

Comment: Please note that debugger arguments can be passed by env variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` which will not be present in the command line

Answer (score 5):

The consensus is: *no*. Java does not have the equivalent of:

- [IsDebuggerPresent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent) *(native Windows)*
- [Debugger.IsAttached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?view=net-6.0) *(.NET)*
- [DebugHook](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.DebugHook) *(Delphi)*

But the consensus:

- [How to programmatically detect whether current JVM is connected by a remote debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71308198/how-to-programmatically-detect-whether-current-jvm-is-connected-by-a-remote-debu)
- [Can a Java application detect that a debugger is attached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393403/can-a-java-application-detect-that-a-debugger-is-attached)
- [Determine if a java application is in debug mode in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109019/determine-if-a-java-application-is-in-debug-mode-in-eclipse)
- [Check whether we are in Intellij IDEA Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754627/check-whether-we-are-in-intellij-idea-debugger)
- [How to find out if "debug mode" is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776204/how-to-find-out-if-debug-mode-is-enabled)

agrees that the best (non-minified) hack is:

```
public static boolean isDebuggerPresent() {
    // Get ahold of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) management interface
    RuntimeMXBean runtime = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

    // Get the command line arguments that we were originally passed in
    List<String> args = runtime.getInputArguments();

    // Check if the Java Debug Wire Protocol (JDWP) agent is used.
    // One of the items might contain something like "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9009,server=y,suspend=n"
    // We're looking for the string "jdwp".
    boolean jdwpPresent = args.toString().contains("jdwp");

    return jdwpPresent;
}
```

Which will have to suffice until Java officially adds one.

Comment: Confirmed that this works with IntelliJ 2023.2.2, running tests with the Gradle test runner with and without debugger attached.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you'd like to do, it might be worthwhile investigating the [`onthrow` JDWP sub-option](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation). I haven't actually tried this ;-) but it seems like you could create a special exception type that you throw and catch to trigger JVM suspension. As shown in the linked examples, combining with `launch` can provide for some interesting alternatives. Of course, the logic/workflow is different from what you've expressed, but it's something to think about...

Answer (score 0):

see [Determine if a java application is in debug mode in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109019/determine-if-a-java-application-is-in-debug-mode-in-eclipse) for detecting debugger

You could user  TimerTask to poll for attachment