# Check if a debugger is attached during the execution of a unit test

Tags: java, debugging, junit

Is there a way to check in JUnit code if the debugger is attached to the current test execution?
In .NET/C# i know this is possible with `Debugger.IsAttached`.

The use case would be to change or completly disable test timeouts when the debugger is attached because this is pretty annoying if you only have about 15 seconds (the defined timeout) for debugging a test.

Comment: As a quick hack, you could always use "evaluate" to set some specific property when you first hit a breakpoint (and within 15 seconds)... but I'm also interested to hear if there is a proper way to do this. Worst case, use command line args or system properties to disable the timeouts...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a 100% fail-safe approach but you can check if the [Java Debug Wire Protocol](http://blog.ioactive.com/2014/04/hacking-java-debug-wire-protocol-or-how.html) (JDWP) is active which is used by the debugger to connect to a JVM. This can be done by checking for input arguments to the JVM as for example in:

```
boolean isDebug() {
  for(String arg : ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()) {
    if(arg.contains("jdwp=")) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

It might however return a false positive if anybody else named something `jdwp` or if the protocol was used for something else. Also, the command might change in the future what makes this hardly fail-safe. This approach is of course not JUnit specific but as JUnit does not have any privileges within a JVM, this is only natural.

Comment: Doesn't that only say if the argument is passed - independently of a debugger being connected? For the connection it should perhaps also check if suspend=y  ?

Comment: You are right here. Most people run debugging out of their IDEs where both typically come along but the above check is no guarantee, that is true.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Rafael answer:

```java
private static boolean isDebug() {
   return ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().stream().anyMatch(arg->arg.contains("jdwp=") && arg.contains("suspend=y"));
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but `suspend=y` is the default value. So, better to check if `suspend=n` is NOT present.