# Check whether we are in Intellij IDEA Debugger

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Is there a way to check whether we are running within the Intellij IDEA debugger from within the running/debugged Java code?

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: @yole: Because I am developing a game that runs in full screen, which hides the mouse cursor. However, when debugging the code I want/need my mouse cursor.

Comment: @yole One reason would be to show debugging information while debugging.

Comment: Another reason is to disable timeouts that would otherwise trigger when you're paused in the debugger to look around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably covers the answer:

[Can a Java application detect that a debugger is attached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393403/can-a-java-application-detect-that-a-debugger-is-attached)

i.e. It's not in general possible to detect whether a debugger has connected, although Android specifically has such a capability: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected%28%29

Here's an almost identical quesiton for Eclipse, with some workarounds - but as yole says, it depends upon what you are actually trying to do.

[Determine if a java application is in debug mode in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109019/determine-if-a-java-application-is-in-debug-mode-in-eclipse)

To determine if the app was *launched* using the debugger you could use this.  A bit ugly, but it works:

```
// This will check if the Java Debug Wire Protocol agent is used.       
boolean isDebug = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.
    getRuntimeMXBean().
    getInputArguments().toString().indexOf("jdwp") >= 0;
```

Comment: boolean isDebug = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean(). getInputArguments().toString().indexOf("jdwp") >= 0;

// This will check if the Java Debug Wire Protocol agent is used.

Comment: Hey, that's awesome. It works very well. I will thus accept your answer, maybe you want to move your comment to the real answer...

Comment: Thanks Matthias, will do