# System.getenv() - Behavior depends on whether debug mode is enabled

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to retrieve the windows directory of my OS.
To get the correct path I tried the following 2 commands:

```
System.getenv().get("WINDIR")
System.getenv().get("SystemRoot")
```

Both commands work, but the strange thing is, that the first command (WINDIR) returns the path only, if I
run the program in debug mode. The latter command (SystemRoot) returns the path only if I run the program **not** in debug mode.

So this program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getenv().get("WINDIR"));
    System.out.println(System.getenv().get("SystemRoot"));
}
```

evaluates to

```
// Debug mode
C:\Windows
null

// No Debug mode
null
C:\Windows
```

Is this a defined behavior?

(My application is Windows specific, and if i speak of debug mode I mean the default Eclipse "Debug as Java Applicaton" run configiguration)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048216/environment-variables-in-eclipse

Comment: Not quite. I run the program in both cases from eclipse. So the environment is the same wheter I run debug mode or not.

Answer (score 1):

**System.getEnv()** is an overloaded method, one implementation having no parameters and one having a String parameter.

- static Map getenv​() Returns an unmodifiable string map view of the current system environment.
- static String getenv​(String name)    Gets the value of the specified environment variable.

You are calling the implementatation with no parameters, and then calling **get()** on the returned **Map**. [From the Javadoc for System.getEnv()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--):

- For **getEnv()**: **The returned map is typically case-sensitive** on all platforms.
- For **getEnv(String)**: On UNIX systems the alphabetic case of name is typically significant, while **on Microsoft Windows systems it is typically not**.

So it is essential for your code to be providing the name of the environment variable in the correct case, specifying **windir** in all lower case, not upper case.

That said, I can't explain the differences you see when running in debug mode at all. If I run the program below - which is just an enhanced version of yours - I get identical results (as expected) regardless of whether it is run in debug mode or not:

```
System.getenv().get() windir=C:\WINDOWS
System.getenv().get() WINDIR=null
System.getenv().get() systemroot=null
System.getenv().get() SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
System.getenv()       windir=C:\WINDOWS
System.getenv()       WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS
System.getenv()       systemroot=C:\WINDOWS
System.getenv()       SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
```

Could you run the code below twice, once in debug mode and once in normal mode, and advise of the results? Also, advise of your environment: Windows version, Eclipse version and Java version.

[This is more of a request for further information than a final answer, but I couldn't fit it all into a comment.]

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class App {

    private final static Pattern debugPattern = Pattern.compile("-Xdebug|jdwp");

    public static boolean isDebugging() {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397584/how-to-know-my-code-is-running-in-debug-mode-in-ide
        // Taken from the code provided by SO user AlexR
        for (String arg : ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()) {
            if (debugPattern.matcher(arg).find()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Running in debug mode? " + App.isDebugging());
        System.out.println("System.getenv().get() windir=" + System.getenv().get("windir"));
        System.out.println("System.getenv().get() WINDIR=" + System.getenv().get("WINDIR"));
        System.out.println("System.getenv().get() systemroot=" + System.getenv().get("systemroot"));
        System.out.println("System.getenv().get() SystemRoot=" + System.getenv().get("SystemRoot"));
        System.out.println("System.getenv()       windir=" + System.getenv("windir"));
        System.out.println("System.getenv()       WINDIR=" + System.getenv("WINDIR"));
        System.out.println("System.getenv()       systemroot=" + System.getenv("systemroot"));
        System.out.println("System.getenv()       SystemRoot=" + System.getenv("SystemRoot"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I´ve run the programm and the output is both: more clear and more confusing.
While the `System.getenv("...")` version  has the same output in normal mode and debug mode, the `System.getenv().get("...")`
version is now really confusing. In the normal run mode the uppercase `SystemRoot` and the lowercase `windir` returns the desired value.
In debug mode, only the uppercase `WINDIR` returns the correct value.  
I´ll add the output to your answer.  
(I´m running Eclipse `Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)` on `Windows 7 64Bit`)

Comment: Do you get the same output? Or is this a plattform specific behaviour?

Comment: @Schlangguru I have already included the output I get in my post above, and I get identical output regardless for the 8 calls to println() whether I am running in debug mode or not. Can you please clarify for which of the 8 tests your results are different to mine?

Comment: Re "is this a plattform specific behaviour?"....perhaps. I am running Java 1.8   in Eclipse Oxygen 2 on Windows 10.

Comment: I get the same output as you if i´m running in normal mode (no debugging).  
In the debug mode only the uppercase `System.getenv().get("WINDIR")` and all `System.getenv("...")` return the correct directory. The rest returns `null`.