# How a java program knows if it has been started by eclipse's `debug` not `run`?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine if a java application is in debug mode in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109019/determine-if-a-java-application-is-in-debug-mode-in-eclipse)

I can start a java program in eclipse by `run as` or `debug as`.

Is there any way in the java code to check if it was started by `run` or `debug`? I want to do something(e.g. reloading resource) when it's in `debug mode` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is really eclipse who does the magic, by launching the jvm in debug mode which opens a tcp port to attach a debugger so, if you wish to check if you're in debug mode you'd probably want to check if that port is taking connections, at least is one way I can think of.