# How can I tell whether my Spring boot application is in debug mode?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'd like to modify how my application works depending on whether the `--debug` switch is present or not. I tried this in my `@Configuration` file:

```
@Value("\${debug}")
lateinit var debug: String
```

but Spring says

> Could not resolve placeholder 'debug' in value "${debug}"

How can I query the state of the `--debug` option?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most robust way to check for debug mode is to query the `Environment`. This will allow you to detect that the mode has been enabled whether that's been done via a command line argument (`--debug`), system property (`-Ddebug`), environment variable (`DEBUG=true`), etc.

You can inject an instance of the `Environment` as you would any other dependency or you can implement `EnvironmentAware`. The `getProperty(String)` method can then be used to retrieve the value of the `debug` property. Spring Boot treats `debug` as being enabled if the `debug` property has a non-null value other than `false`:

```
private boolean isSet(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, String property) {
    String value = environment.getProperty(property);
    return (value != null && !value.equals("false"));
}
```

Comment: I ended up checking the command line parameter before Spring starts (before I call `SpringApplication.run()`) but this is a more idiomatic way I guess.

Comment: Is the property name on Environment always lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible to get debug mode this way.

Spring looks for any property values here but `--debug` is not part of property.

The debug detecting could be vendor specific. (see [Determine if a java application is in debug mode in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109019/determine-if-a-java-application-is-in-debug-mode-in-eclipse) for more info about debug detecting).

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is makes `debug` option to a system property, for example:

```
java -Ddebug Application
```

then you can annotated the property as below:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties.debug != null}")
var debug: Boolean = false;
//                    ^--- using a default value to avoiding NPException
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because the `--debug` option is a special flag handled by Spring. I can't use it in another way.

Comment: @AdamArold sir, thanks for your feedback. but the `--debug` option only available in `spring-boot` rather than `spring`.

Comment: That's why I tagged my question with it.

Comment: @AdamArold sir, I'm sorry I  don't see the title clearly. but you can change other names for the debug, e.g: `dev`. for the option `debug!` you need change the expression to  `systemProperties['debug!'] != null`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned before in [the reply by Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44631241/222044), it is possible to evaluate the property `debug`, however you need to do this from the `Environment`.

I ran into the same problem, when I wanted to activate a component, only in "debug mode". You can achieve this by using `@ConditionalOnProperty("debug")`, which does fetch the information from `Environment` and thus works with `--debug`, `-Ddebug`, …