# How to get a boolean variable DEBUG in a Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

How to find out if a project is in debug mode and get a variable of a logical type in the thymeleaf template.

`<h1 th:if="${DEBUG}">...</h1>`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "in debug mode"?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this while injecting the `Environment` bean to your contorller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/public")
public class PublicController {

  private final Environment environment;

  public PublicController(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  @GetMapping("/debug")
  public String returnFoo(Model model) {

    String envValue = environment.getProperty("debug");
    boolean isDebugMode = (envValue != null && !envValue.equals("false"));
    model.addAttribute("DEBUG", isDebugMode);

    System.out.println(isDebugMode);

    return "yourView";
  }
}
```

This is implementation is working for every possible way you might set the `debug` flag to your application ([How can I tell whether my Spring boot application is in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629885/how-can-i-tell-whether-my-spring-boot-application-is-in-debug-mode))